# ZF2 Rest Api call not goes to proper function on Linux Server

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework2, lamp

I used ZF2 REST Api module which is working fine in windows environment, but if i Run this application on Linux Environment then call not goes to proper function.
Example:

1) I hit url from postman on windows,
   Url : `myapi.net/api/testing/scp.vp@gmail.com`
   here,
     `api`-module,  `testing`-controller,  `scp.vp@gmail.com`-parameter
     Method : POST => Works Fine, call goes to `create()` function.

2) Same Url hit on Linux, then call not goes to `create()` function and called       `get()` function
If i change the parameter and remove 'scp' from email then it works properly on Linux, might be problem with `**scp**`

Thanks,

Comment: It is interesting. I think there is likely a simple mistake somewhere, rather than problem with Linux. Is version of your programme the same on both environments?

Comment: @OleksandrKaleniuk Yes, I used ZF 2.3.3 for both enviromnments

Comment: Can you show a route config for that controller?

Comment: 'options' => array (
  'route' => "/:controller[/:id]",
  'constraints' => array (
    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
    'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-_@+\.]*' 
  ) 
 )

Comment: Ok, let me think. BTW if you use Apache, make sure .htaccess files are the same on both env

Comment: .htaccess is same, I think it is issue related 'scp' bcoz, linux uses this command to copy file, but not get exact solution!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123951/discussion-between-vishal-vasantrao-patil-and-oleksandr-kaleniuk).

Comment: "@" and + sign need to escape. please note, i'm not telling that you solve your problem :D